# border-radius + background-color == cropped border

Tags: html, border, background-color, css

Consider a `div` with the `border-radius`, `border`, and `background-color` CSS attributes applied:

```html
<div style="background-color:#EEEEEE; border-radius:10px; border: 1px black solid;">
  Blah
</div>
```

[image]

Now consider a similar layout but with the `background-color` specified in an inner-div:

```html
<div style="border-radius:10px; border: 1px black solid;">
  <div style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">
    Blah
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I'm dismayed by the fact that the `background-color` of the *inner* `<div>` is obscuring the border of the *outer* `<div>`.

This is a simplified sample of the problem.  In reality, I'm using a `<table>` as the inner element with alternating row colors.  And I'm using a `<div>` as the outer element since `border-radius` does not seem to work on the `<table>` element. [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpNy7/9/) of a sample of this problem.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a solution?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Try `overflow: hidden` in the outer `div`:

```html
<div style="border-radius:10px; border: 1px black solid; overflow: hidden">
  <div style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">
    Blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: yeah, it worked to me but what does it do `overflow:hidden` here? is just a plain hack? or does it have a proper reason? thanks a lot

Comment: It hides overflowing background outside its parent, clean and simple solution.

Answer (score 14):

You can fix this by applying `overflow: hidden;` to the element with the border. A much cleaner way I think.

Answer (score 9):

Add these CSS rules:

```
tr:first-of-type td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;    
}

tr:first-of-type td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;    
}

tr:last-of-type td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;    
}

tr:last-of-type td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;    
}
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zyht/).

Comment: This is very nice.  I would prefer a version that worked in IE8 but will take this if it's the best that can be done.

Answer (score 4):

You could add `border-radius` to the child element too.

```html
<div style="border-radius:10px; border: 1px black solid;">
  <div style="background-color:#EEEEEE; border-radius:10px;">
    Blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Does a table have to be used? Here's an example using DIV's: http://jsfiddle.net/6KwGy/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="leftHalf">
            <p>data 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightHalf">
            <p>data 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="leftHalf">
            <p>data 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightHalf">
            <p>data 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="leftHalf">
            <p>data 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightHalf">
            <p>data 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.leftHalf {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.rightHalf {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.row {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#container .row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#container .row:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius-topright: 5px;
}
#container .row:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
}
#container .row {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: +1 for exploring other options.  But since this uses `last-child` it too won't work in IE8, so I figure I'm best off using melhosseiny's solution.  (it being shorter)

Comment: I see, you could always create a unique class for the first and last row that contains the border-radius style.

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding, or do the background color on the outer element

Comment: I cannot add padding for design reasons.  And as I mentioned, the background color in my real app is from *alternating* row colors, which would be impossible to define on the outer element.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to give the div a little padding? That way the background colors wouldn't conflict.

Comment: No, it's important to me that the background-color be flush with the border.  (i.e., I don't want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jpNy7/10/))